# type error is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  search function and this function is executing after click search button, my problem is when search button clicked, it shows an error saying `TypeError: KeyWord.searchStation is not a function`. Could anyone explain why getting this error in my snapped code?

Code:

```
    search: function () {

        var self = this;
        var id = $("#in_id").val();
        var state_code = document.getElementById('sel_state').value;
        var type_code = document.getElementById('type_code').value;


        KeyWord.searchStation(state_code, type_code,
            function (data) {
                $("#view_table").ViewTable('option', 'data', data);
                console.log(data);
                //location.reload();
            },
            function (error) {
                jqXhrErr(error);
            },
            function () {
                Metronic.unblockUI();
            });
    }

var KeyWord = function () {

    var url_station = "api/station/Search";
    return {
        searchStation: function (state_code, type_code, done, fail, always) {
            var jqxhr = $.get(url_station, { state_code: state_code, type_code: type_code });
            return jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
        },
    }
}();
```

Comment: Can you log the value of `KeyWord.searchStation` before it is used? like `console.log(KeyWord.searchStation)` and see what is logged in the browser console

Comment: I have tried that but it did not log anything.

Comment: Can you try `console.log('KeyWord', KeyWord)` just before `KeyWord.searchStation(state_code, type_code,...`

Comment: Thanks to @Arun P Johny, `KeyWord' was referring to different object as shown in logged object which developed by different developer.

Comment: Make sure the statement var KeyWord = function() { .... runs before the Keyword.searchStation statement.